# Error while converting query from mysql to oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, oracle10g

I have four queries in mysql in my webapp that I am trying to convert into oracle queries. However, the datetime string breaks when I try to run the new query. Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

PostreSQL Queries:-

> insert into o_stat_daily 
>                                     (businesspath,resid,day,value)
>                                     (select businesspath, 
>                                         int8(substring(businesspath from position(':' in businesspath) + 1 for position(']' in businesspath) - position(':' in
>   businesspath) - 1)),
>                                         date_trunc('day',creationdate) as d,
>                                         count(*) as c 
>                                     from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != '' group by businesspath, d);
>
> insert into o_stat_weekly
>                                     (businesspath,resid,week,value)
>                                     (select businesspath, 
>                                         int8(substring(businesspath from position(':' in businesspath) + 1 for position(']' in businesspath) - position(':' in
>   businesspath) - 1)),
>                                         to_char(creationdate, 'IYYY') || '-' || to_char(creationdate, 'IW') as d,
>                                         count(*) as c 
>                                     from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != '' group by businesspath, d);
>
> insert into o_stat_dayofweek
>                                     (businesspath,resid,day,value)
>                                     (select businesspath, 
>                                         int8(substring(businesspath from position(':' in businesspath) + 1 for position(']' in businesspath) - position(':' in
>   businesspath) - 1)), 
>                                         int8(to_char(creationdate, 'D')) as d,
>                                         count(*) as c 
>                                     from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != '' group by businesspath, d);
>
> insert into o_stat_hourofday
>                                     (businesspath,resid,hour,value)
>                                     (select businesspath, 
>                                         int8(substring(businesspath from position(':' in businesspath) + 1 for position(']' in businesspath) - position(':' in
>   businesspath) - 1)), 
>                                         int8(to_char(creationdate, 'HH24')) as d,
>                                         count(*) as c 
>                                     from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != '' group by businesspath, d);

Oracle Queries:-

> insert into o_stat_daily 
>                                         (businesspath,resid,day,value)
>                                         (select businesspath, 
>                                             convert(substr(businesspath, locate(':', businesspath) + 1, locate(']', businesspath) - locate(':', businesspath) - 1), int), 
>                                             convert(creationdate,date) d,
>                                             count(*)  c 
>                                         from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != ''  group by businesspath, d);
>
> insert into o_stat_weekly
>                                     (businesspath,resid,week,value)
>                                     (select businesspath, 
>                                         convert(substr(businesspath, locate(':', businesspath) + 1, locate(']', businesspath) - locate(':', businesspath) - 1), int), 
>                                         year(creationdate)+ '-'+repeat('0',2-length(convert((dayofyear(creationdate)-dayofweek(creationdate))/7,varchar(7))))+convert((dayofyear(creationdate)-dayofweek(creationdate))/7,varchar(7))
>   d,
>                                         count(*)  c 
>                                     from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != '' group by businesspath, d);
>
> insert into o_stat_dayofweek
>                                     (businesspath,resid,day,value)
>                                     (select businesspath, 
>                                         convert(substr(businesspath, locate(':', businesspath) + 1, locate(']', businesspath) - locate(':', businesspath) - 1), int), 
>                                         dayofweek(creationdate) d,
>                                         count(*)  c 
>                                     from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != ''  group by businesspath, d);
>
> insert into o_stat_hourofday
>                                     (businesspath,resid,hour,value)
>                                     (select businesspath, 
>                                         convert(substr(businesspath, locate(':', businesspath) + 1, locate(']', businesspath) - locate(':', businesspath) - 1), int), 
>                                         hour(creationdate) d,
>                                         count(*)  c 
>                                     from o_loggingtable where actionverb='launch' and actionobject='node' and businesspath != ''  group by businesspath, d);

Comment: It might help to break down your question into fixing just one of your queries and the information gleaned from that should help you to fix the other ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rewrite all your queries, I have taken just the last one.

The oracle query should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO o_stat_hourofday (
   businesspath,
   resid,
   hour,
   VALUE
)
SELECT businesspath,
       TO_NUMBER (
          SUBSTR (
             businesspath,
             INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
             INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
          )
       ),
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(creationdate, 'HH24')) d,
       COUNT (*) c
  FROM o_loggingtable
 WHERE actionverb = 'launch'
   AND actionobject = 'node'
   AND businesspath IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY businesspath,
          TO_NUMBER (
             SUBSTR (
                businesspath,
                INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
                INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
             )
          ), 
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(creationdate, 'HH24'));
```

FYI, Oracle does not recognise the `HOUR` function and `CONVERT` in oracle converts one character set to another, not a string to a numeric. LOCATE is not an Oracle function either, you need to use `INSTR` instead to find a character in a string.

Read up on [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) (including date formats etc), [TO_NUMBER](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php) and [INSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I've also aded the remaining three queries. All of them are working. Thanks for the help Ollie.

```
INSERT INTO o_stat_daily (
   businesspath,
   resid,
   DAY,
   VALUE
)
SELECT businesspath,
       TO_NUMBER (
          SUBSTR (
             businesspath,
             INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
             INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
          )
       ),
       to_date(creationdate)
       d,
       COUNT (*) c
  FROM o_loggingtable
 WHERE actionverb = 'launch'
   AND actionobject = 'node'
   AND businesspath IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY businesspath,
          TO_NUMBER (
             SUBSTR (
                businesspath,
                INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
                INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
             )
          ), 
          to_date(creationdate);



INSERT INTO o_stat_weekly (
   businesspath,
   resid,
   WEEK,
   VALUE
)
SELECT businesspath,
       TO_NUMBER (
          SUBSTR (
             businesspath,
             INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
             INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
          )
       ),
       to_char(creationdate, 'IYYY') || '-' || to_char(creationdate, 'IW') 
       d,
       COUNT (*) c
  FROM o_loggingtable
 WHERE actionverb = 'launch'
   AND actionobject = 'node'
   AND businesspath IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY businesspath,
          TO_NUMBER (
             SUBSTR (
                businesspath,
                INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
                INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
             )
          ), 
          to_char(creationdate, 'IYYY') || '-' || to_char(creationdate, 'IW') ;

INSERT INTO o_stat_dayofweek (
   businesspath,
   resid,
   day,
   VALUE
)
SELECT businesspath,
       TO_NUMBER (
          SUBSTR (
             businesspath,
             INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
             INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
          )
       ),
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(creationdate, 'D')) d,
       COUNT (*) c
  FROM o_loggingtable
 WHERE actionverb = 'launch'
   AND actionobject = 'node'
   AND businesspath IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY businesspath,
          TO_NUMBER (
             SUBSTR (
                businesspath,
                INSTR(businesspath, ':') + 1,
                INSTR(businesspath, ']') - INSTR(businesspath, ':') - 1
             )
          ), 
          TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(creationdate, 'D'));
```